# Wcf The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I have created some wcfs. One of them when i have tried to run it produced the picture below [image]

When i have created the config and cs files and tried to run it with the code mentioned in the picture above after i have edited the web.config file of the web form from where it would be called the following comes up:

[image]

At this point, i read in similar posts about microsoft service trace viewer and svclog files. But since i am pretty new at this no helpful info could come out from the files. Any help would be really appreciated

I think that posting here all the text would be a bit too big, though i can upload the photo in a cloud. I have changed a bit the name of the web service as its functions the error though remains the same.

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Icheck_product" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:51182/check_product.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Icheck_product"
                contract="Icheck_product" name="BasicHttpBinding_Icheck_product" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The above is the output.config and the one below is the web.config after i added data from the above:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEncrypt_Data" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGetDbConnection" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Icheck_product" />


      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:50776/Encrypt_Data.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IEncrypt_Data" contract="Encypt_Data_Reference.IEncrypt_Data"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IEncrypt_Data" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:50776/GetDbConnection.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IGetDbConnection"
        contract="Get_Db_Connection.IGetDbConnection" name="BasicHttpBinding_IGetDbConnection" />


      <endpoint address="http://localhost:51182/check_product.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Icheck_product"
    contract="Icheck_product" name="BasicHttpBinding_Icheck_product" />

    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Lastly the updated image of the error can be found here: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Fw3rEXlvPTeURQbm9rVWtkdzg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please post info on WCF Configuration like Binding, endpoints etc.

Comment: Hi, rather than post screenshots, it's much better to just copy and paste the text of the page/exception.

Comment: Please check the edits in my main post

Comment: First, check the event viewer on the server hosting the service.  It's a good bet it will tell you what the error was there.  Second, do what the error message tells you - set IncludeExceptionDetailsInFaults to true in the *service* config.   9 times out of 10 one of those two will tell you what went wrong in the method `check1`.  Something in your code threw an exception - the 2 items I recommend are just about guaranteed to help you find out what.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error in a service I created.  What I did was change this line in the web.config file:
serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" to "true" 
It gives a lot better detail explanation, in my case it was a typo in my connection string